# ASP.NET MVC combining radio buttons with text box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating form where user will enter some information. I am using EF for storing this information into DB. I want implement here a 3 radio buttons. When user select third radio button, named like 'other', I want to show some text box and then store this text from text box to database. How can I do this?

I tried something, but it only store to DB value from that third radio button, not from text box.

```
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Type,"Material Master")
      @Html.Label("Material Master")
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Type, "Packaging Master")
      @Html.Label("Packaging Master")
      @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Type, "Other")
      @Html.Label("Other")
      @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Type, new { @disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control" })
```

Can someone show me the way, how can be this done? I have no idea what can I do.

Model:

```
public class RequisitionHeader
{
    [Key]
    public int RequisitionId { get; set; }
    public string Applicant { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public string ReasonOfChange { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ValidityOfChangeFrom { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What does you model look like?

Comment: I added model. You can look at it

Comment: I would move the model.type from the radio button for "other" to the text box where the user types "other".

Answer (score 1):

I would use next:

```
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Type,"Material Master") Material Master</label>
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Type,"Packaging Master") Packaging Master</label>
<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Type,"Other") Other</label>
```

Or write your own mvc html helper